# What's sufficient for storing timezones?

Tags: php

I need to store client timezones and am wondering if I need to take DST into consideration. All I care about is displaying the user's local timezone and if DST is in effect, then the system should reflect it.

Is it enough to set the user's timezone using `date_default_timezone_set` and assume that DST will be automatically calculated if there is one for that area?

Is there anything else that I need to do to safeguard that the user be shown the correct time?

**EDIT:**
Some great answers here, thanks.

If I store the users timestamps in UTC, regardless of their actual timezone and I use `date_default_timezone_set` to convert the UNIX timestamp, will the correct time be displayed if there is a DST present?

Comment: Store as UST, store timezone as `Europe/London` (or whatever is the appropriate timezone) and use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects

Comment: Thanks Mark. UST or UTC? Which is better and why, plz

Comment: If you only want to display it, you might consider not handling client timezones or local time on the server side at all, sending only UTC UNIX time integers, and using Javascript in the client browser to convert it to whatever time the client thinks is local time. This has the added benefit of not having to worry about possible DST rule differences between the server & the client OSes (every now and then DST rules change, so they can get out of sync).

Comment: @LaszloValko, thanks. I'd like to keep it as simple as possible and your solution sounds like it would work out well. The way I've got it now, I'm storing the user's time after using `date_default_timezone_set`. Would this present issues for me if I left it like this?

Comment: What actually happens with daylight savings is that we change to a different timezone. Like here, we just changed from CEST(GMT+2) to CET(GMT+1). If you use the country-specific zones (like @MarkBaker says, "Europe/London"), the correct timezone for the current time of year will be chosen. Btw. it is best to convert to and store all times as GMT to avoid mess.

Comment: @Atle, thanks also. So, I'm in NA and our clients are all over the USA. So, you're saying to store the timestamps in GMT and then use the user's timezone, such as America/Pacific?

Comment: UTC, or GMT as it used to be called, doesn't have daylight saving etc. For example UK has daylight saving, so they go UTC+01:00. I would go for the UTC UNIX, this will always be correct, and then just adjust that to whatever timezone the end-user/client is when outputting to them. You can even give them the option to set their own time zone depending on what it is compared to UTC.

Comment: Thanks Horse. I've been told to always use UTC as well. So, my timestamps will all be stored as UTC and then would I just apply the user's tz to display the correct time? WOuld this work?

Comment: @Nan, yes. Before you store the timezone you should check that it really exists, PHP has a list of valid timezones here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php. If you run `date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles")`, all times printed with functions like `date()` will be converted to the current timezone in Los Angeles.

Comment: @Atle, I have a list of 30 unique PHP timezones in a dropdown for the user to choose from. What I am currently doing is changing the timezone for each user for their respective timezone then storing any timestamps. I'm expecting that if DST is present that the correct time will be displayed.

Comment: @Nan, if you store as GMT, the user can change his timezone settings later if he wants to without you having to convert all timestamps in the DB from the old TZ to the new :) Also, time functions in PHP accept timestamps (seconds from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT), so it's best to store timestamps.

Comment: (I really mean UTC when I write GMT, sorry about that)

Comment: @Atle, I should probably know the difference between GMT and UTC but I don't. I'll have to look this up later. OK, I will use GMT to store all of my timestamps with and also, I am storing my stamps as UNIX time

Comment: :)  Got it.. OK, so UTC it is. My question now is, to display the correct time back to the user, how would I do this? If the client is in America/Pacific, would I set the timezone for his area and then display the time?

Comment: I created an answer we can use to summarize all this info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably best to store dates and times as the UTC+0. When you print out dates to the user in PHP, functions like  `date()` accept a timestamp argument. These functions also automatically converts the timestamp to the current timezone. Timestamps are always UTC+0.

In a PHP script, you can change the default timezone like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Oslo");
```

After that, I get this result while running `date("r")`:

```
Sun, 27 Oct 2013 11:22:52 +0100
```

When you use geographic timezone names, times will be converted to the correct timezone depending on which time of year it is. In my example, "CET(GMT+1)" is chosen now, but yesterday it would have given me the daylight savings timezone "CEST(GMT+2)".

To store the current time in for instance a database, you can usually just store timestamps as integers (`INT(11)`). The current UTC+0 timestamp is in PHP retrieved with `time()`.

Comment: Cheers. Just a hint, I cannot find "America/Pacific" in the list on php.net, but you'll probably figure that out sooner or later :)

Comment: `time()` gives you UTC+0 timestamps regardless of what timezone you set.

Comment: Yes but only when you use the geographic names. If I use "Europe/Oslo", it will select "CET" or "CEST" for me automatically. However if I use names like "CET" or "Etc/GMT+1", it will always give me "GMT+1" regardless of daylight savings.

Comment: Atle, thank you very much for all your help and thank you for putting up with me. :)